# Selecting tableView cell with collectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to select it but I can not

I use both methods

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I want to select full cell if I touch some element or any background

=====update
I want to select cell and catch this touch

=====update2
I got custom cell with coolectionView in it, I override layoutSubviews method, it need me to display collections

```
 -(void)layoutSubviews
```

{
    [super layoutSubviews];

```
self.collectionView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
```

Then I turn it off all works, but I can not see my collections

Comment: Please elaborate, it's not clear what you want to accomplish and how.

Comment: I want to select cell and catch this touch

Comment: The method is called select, it doesn't mean you can drag-select them as in your desktop. In this content means "the cell was tapped upon". Try adding NSLog(@"%@", indexPath) inside these methods. The console will show you which cell was tapped showing the indexPath.

Comment: I am forgot to add some important text

Comment: Hey bro, you better describe in more detail what you want to accomplish here, because your question is not clear, why do you override layoutSubviews?